# SetParent causes my WPF window to become invisible

Tags: wpf, windows, hwnd

I'm writing a program in WPF which will make a `Window` appear overlaid on top of a specific Win32 window in another process.

So far this generally works:

1. Get the `hWnd` of the window I want to overlay (the target).
2. Instantiate my overlay window (`class Overlay : Window`) and show it (`overlay.Show()`).
3. Call `SetWinEventHook` for the target for both the `LocationChange` and `Destroy` events.
4. In the callback for `SetWinEventHook` for `LocationChange` I reposition my `Overlay` instance to match the rectangle of the target window.

The problem is that my `Overlay` instance appears behind the target window in the z-axis. I can work-around this by setting `Topmost = true`, but then my window is on top of all windows, not just the target.

I tried calling `SetParent( new WindowInteropHelper( overlay ).Handle, targetWindowHandle )` however when this happens my overlay window disappears. Calling `overlay.Show()` has no effect. I also tried it with `SetWindowLongPtr` (though MSDN says not to call this with `GWL_HWNDPARENT`) to no avail.

Why does `SetParent` make my window invisible, and what's the best way (if not this) to ensure my window remains on-top of another specific window?

Comment: Stop trying to do this. See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx) for why it's so bad. "it is technically legal.

It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws ... near-impossible to manage if one or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sage advice. How do programs like Lync/"Skype-for-Business" implement their overlays then?